# django_hosts - NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'home' not found. 'home' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django, django-hosts

Versions:

```
Django                   2.2.10
django-hosts             4.0
```

I have installed django_hosts successfully as [per this documentation](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-to-set-up-subdomains-Django-website.php).

I can successfully now access pages like https://blog.mysite.com

However, the urls on the page are **NOT** resolved correctly. I have followed the example shown in the [django_hosts official documentation](https://django-hosts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

This is what my setup looks like:

#### mysite/urls.py

```
# imports etc. truncated for brevity 
# ...

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(('home.urls', 'home'), namespace='home')),   
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls', namespace="blog")),
    # ...
]
```

### home/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include, url 

from .views import HomePageView, AboutView, TermsView, PrivacyView, \
                    sample, register, signin

app_name = 'home'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('about', AboutView.as_view(), name='about'),
    path('terms', TermsView.as_view(), name='terms'),
    path('privacy', PrivacyView.as_view(), name='privacy'),

    path('sample', sample),    
    path('register', register, name='register'),
    path('signin', signin, name='signin'),
]
```

### blog/templates/index.html

```
                    <div class="container">
116                     <!-- Logo -->
117                     <a class="logo" href="{% host_url 'home' host 'www' %}" style="text-decoration: none; font-size: 250%;">
118                         <img src="/static/assets/img/logo.png">
119                         My Site
120                     </a>                    
121                     <!-- End Logo -->
```

**[[ Edit ]]**

The actual demo is [uploaded to github](https://github.com/Pointer2VoidStar/subdomain-demo)

Comment: home is a namesapce not a url. where the href should go ?

Comment: I don't see how you followed the linked documentation. There's virtually nothing alike.

Comment: @Melvyn first link shows how to install and setup `django_hosts` app. Official documentation link shows how to use `host_url` template tag.

Comment: @EricMartin I don't understand your comment. Please clarify

Comment: [This documentation](https://django-hosts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) shows the use of `host` instead of `path` for urlpatterns and a different application structure. What @EricMartin means is that your call signature for [include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/#include) is incorrect. Your first member of the tuple should be an iterable of patterns not a module reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

below how i managed to solve the issue

```
. mysite

  .. blog  # Blog app
     .. __init__.py
     .. urls.py

  .. home  # Home app
     .. __init__.py
     .. urls.py


  .. mysite

     .. urls
        .. __init__.py
        .. blog.py
        .. home.py

     .. settings.py

     .. hosts.py
```

in `mysite/settings.py`

```
[..]

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
              'mysite.com',
         'blog.mysite.com',
]

[..]


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django_hosts.middleware.HostsRequestMiddleware',  # django hosts

    [..]

    'django_hosts.middleware.HostsResponseMiddleware',  # django hosts
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls.home'

# django-hosts
# https://django-hosts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#settings

ROOT_HOSTCONF = 'mysite.hosts'

DEFAULT_HOST = 'www'  # HERE see hosts.py

PARENT_HOST = 'mysite.com'

# HOST_SCHEME = 'http'

# HOST_PORT = 8000

# HOST_SITE_TIMEOUT = 3600

[..]
```

in `mysite/hosts.py`

```
from django.conf import settings

from django_hosts import patterns, host


host_patterns = patterns('',

    # mysite.com
    host(r'^$', 'settings.ROOT_URLCONF', name='www'),  # see 'settings.py'

    # blog.mysite.com
    host(r'blog', 'mysite.urls.blog', name='blog'),
)
```

in `mysite/urls/home.py`

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('',       include('home.urls', namespace='home')),

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),  # Admin Area
]

[..]
```

in `mysite/urls/blog.py`

```
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('apps.blog.urls', namespace='blog')),

]

[..]
```

in `blog/templates/index.html`

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- Logo -->
    
     <!-- HERE you don't need to specify host 'www' since it defaults to 'www' see settings.py -->
    <a class="logo" href="{% url 'home:index' %}" style="text-decoration: none; font-size: 250%;">
        <img src="/static/assets/img/logo.png">
        My Site
    </a>
    <!-- End Logo -->
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I notice that you have an unsual directory structure: there is a `mysite/urls` folder. Is this intentional, or a mistake? Also, is this unusual structure required to make the `django_hosts` ap work correctly when routing URLs?

Comment: yes it is intentional and not a mistake, it's simply a python package (`__init__.py`) to make the application modular and easy to extend and to maintain.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli you may have a look at the source code of `djangoproject.com` https://github.com/django/djangoproject.com/tree/master/djangoproject and you'll get the idea

Comment: But isn't it standard (i.e. recommend) practise to have each application fully self contained and 'independent'? So for example app `foo` would have it urls.py accessible at `foo.urls'. In this case, the urls for each app is stored under the `urls` folder of the main project - this is a departure from recommended practise - or am I missing something here

Comment: yes but i think you are confused between `app` level and `project/global` `urls.py` files.
in `foo/urls.py` you define all routes/paths regarding `foo` app and then you make them available/recognizable **globally** in `project/global` `urls.py` next to `settings.py` file via `include`

Comment: yes, what you described in your last comment, is the standard (i.e. recommended way) to structure a django application (and that's how my project is structured). However, the answer you gave, has a different project layout - with apps having their urls in the `mysite/urls` folder. I would have to do a major refactor of my code to use this non-standard layout - that is why I was asking whether this non-standard project layout is the only way to get routing with `django-hosts` to work. Is that the case?

Comment: for `django-hosts` it's often good practice to separate **urls confs** depending on **sub-domains** you need that's why the former **global** `urls.py` usually one is splitted

Comment: I see. That makes sense. I'll see if I can somehow get it to work with my existing project layout - If I don't succeed, I'll have no choice but to use the new project layout you suggested - even though that means a lot of refactoring at my end

Comment: refer to to doc `host(r'(foo|bar)', 'path.to.urls', name='foo-or-bar'),`  `path.to.urls` is the key

Comment: in your case just make difference between `app namespace` and `host name`, i usually choose the same name to avoid confusion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223470/discussion-between-homunculus-reticulli-and-cizario).

Comment: No. I have tried pretty much everything and the issue remains. The problem seems to be with reverse resolving url names when using `django_hosts`. I am currently looking at using another django app if need be, to implement subdomains.

Comment: Problem is that if I have a base template with page headings (for example) that contain links to the homepage etc., the current issue I m having means that the page `http://localhost` works fine whereas `http://blog.localhost` does not, because I get an error like: `NoReverseMatch at / 'home' is not a registered namespace`. Even though the page header was displayed correctly at `http://localhost`

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli did you setup `vhosts` ?

Comment: I have uploaded code for a demo that replicates the problem, to github, so you can see what I'm actually doing. See here: https://github.com/Pointer2VoidStar/subdomain-demo

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli the issue should be now solved (i wasted much time with my very old machine) and it works on windows7 win 32, wampserver2.5, python 3.8.7, refer to this repo : https://github.com/cizario/subdomain-demo, i know i should fork it but ...